# Problems with extra keyboards in ubuntu after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, keyboard-layout, mate

After upgrade from `ubuntu mate 16.04` I have troubles with adding extra keyboard layouts in my `ubuntu mate 20.04`
I have 2 partitions: `/home` and `/`
`/home` is living with my installations since `ubuntu 10.10`
`/` is reformatted all times after `ubuntu` upgrade
I'm simply not able to add any layouts.
If I try to add in keyboard settings new keyboard, this window freezes.
When i start `mate-keyboard-properties` from `terminal` and try to add keyboard,i'm getting following message in `terminal`[image: Error]

Keyboard preferences window freezes and does not response on any other clicks.
Is it problem with my older configs from previous installations?
How can i repair it?

**UPD**
New user is able to add layouts for his session.
It is not working for my user.

Comment: Can you create an additional user for test purposes and let us know if keyboard layout management works as expected for that user.

Comment: It is working fine with test user

Comment: That confirms that the problem lies in your `$HOME` and that the suggestion in [da_kingpin](https://askubuntu.com/users/1029525/da-kingpin)'s answer is a reasonable approach. Personally I would try to move away `~/.cache` also.

Comment: Suggestion of @da_kingpin is bit overkill. I would like to restrict this changes only to mate settings and not for all settings of all my applications.

Comment: Then you probably need a MATE expert. If you are lucky some of those sees this, but you may want to also try https://ubuntu-mate.community/

Comment: I can understand why you would hesitate to remove the '~/.config' folder. It sounds much worse than it really is. It would bring you back as though you created a new user. You would be to restore any custom configurations from the backup folder as necessary. Drag and drop with a file manager if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been carrying your `/home` directory since 10.10 then yes, it ***may*** be time to remove some old config files in your home dir. Most applications store config files in your home directory in the `~/.config` folder, or in their own respective hidden directory `~/.<application-name>` .

Be sure to backup any files before making changes. And as a precaution have a live image available.

To list your hidden files and directories from terminal `ls -ld .?*`

Most application will rebuild default config settings when reopened after removing the config directory.

***DICLAIMER***
Not responsible for anything. Proceed at your own risk!!!  ***DISCLAIMER***

Now with that out of the way, it is really not that bad.

Since you have been a user since 10.10, I presume you are an experience user.

From terminal `mv ~/.config  ~/.config.backup` or

`mv ~/.<application>  ~/.<application>.backup`

logout, then login.

It will take some time for the default desktop config files to be reinstalled. If there are any problems you can reboot into a LiveImage or using a recovery mode menu entry from grub and simply move the backup copy you previously made back by

`mv /home/<your-dir>/.config.backup /home/<your-dir>/.config`

Comment: I think that it bit overkill. Remove all settings of all apps. I think that it should be connected only to mate/gnome2 settings.

Comment: You are correct. It is overkill. That is why I suggested backing up the .config folder first. Over time many setting and configurations can be changed with conflicting configurations set. So this is recommended as a troubleshooting first step. Just to determine if a configuration is the culprit. You could then begin to narrow it down as necessary. I should have been more detailed in that suggestion I suppose.